# Linux kernel API changes/additions

Tags: linux-kernel, documentation

I'm trying to find a webpage or docs or XYZ that will allow me to see all the API changes/additions/removals between two kernel versions.

I found http://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxChanges, but I'm not sure it lists everything as I know that Netlink API changed somewhere between 3.5 and 3.6 but it doesn't appear on that page.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the analysis report for the Linux kernel ABI [here](http://abi-laboratory.pro/tracker/timeline/linux/):

[image]

Comment: it doesnt work now, do you know any alternatives?

Comment: @leo Do uoy need a report for 6.1?

Comment: @leo just ping the developer

Comment: I needed to find changes in API between 3.10, 4.18, 5.4 & 6.0 kernels. I've done it manually comparing sources :)